# How to calculate total price of shopping cart in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My `productSchema` is like so:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number
 });
```

And my `POST` @ `'/charge'` endpoint controller is:

```
const sendCharge = async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body // => [{ _id, quantity }, ...]

  // calculate total price of items here using prices of products found on database
}
```

In my `sendCharge` controller, how can I use mongoDB or mongoose operations to calculate the **total price** of all of the `items`, with respect to their quantities, posted by the client?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> db.products.aggregate([{
> $group: {
> _id: 0,
> totPrice: {
> $sum: '$price'
> },
> totProduct: {
> $sum: 1
> }
> }
> }])